# Automated Uninstall Service via MSI Not Working

Tags: powershell, windows-services, windows-installer, build-automation, powershell-remoting

I am writing a powershell script to deploy a .NET 4 Windows Service to a 2008 server via a generated MSI.  A fresh installation runs fine, but when I rerun and it tries to uninstall it, the script hangs while trying to do the uninstall.  I call msiexec, which runs on the target machine (I can see the process started when the uninstall is running).  The only differences between the uninstall and install code is the log name and the /x command passed to msiexec.

Here is the code that I have:

```
function UninstallService ($serverName, $fileName)
{
    write "Start uninstall service."

    $msiNamePath = "C:\MsiDeployment\" + $fileName
    $processArgs = @("/i", $msiNamePath, "/x", "/qn", "/norestart", "/l", "c:\msiuninstall.log")

    # Create session
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $serverName

    # Enter session
    Enter-PSSession $session

    # Do uninstall
    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { param($pArgs,$rootDir) Start-Process -FilePath "$rootDir\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $pArgs -Wait } -Args $processArgs,("$env:systemroot\system32")

    # Close session    
    Exit-PSSession
    Remove-PSSession $session

    if (!$?) { throw "Could not uninstall the service remotely on machine " + $serverName }

    write "End uninstall service."
}
```

If I terminate the running msiexec on the server, the script continues on processing (fails later due to checking if the service is uninstalled).  I'm guessing that there is some prompt that is looking for user input (maybe UAC), but I'm not entirely certain. I get no log file on the uninstall, but install writes the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figured out the issue.  I left the /i flag in the arguments when it should have just been the /x flag. Works fine now.

The flag was the msiexec throwing an error page even when the qn flag was passed to it. Not sure if it should have done that.

Comment: how about the enter and exit ps session? Does it work with those statements in the script?

Answer (score 0):

`Enter-PSSession` is meant only for interactive use and not in a script. So, essentially, your script stops working after `Enter-PSSession $session`.

Remove the following lines from your script and everything should work as expected.

```
 # Enter session
    Enter-PSSession $session

  # Close session    
    Exit-PSSession
```

All you need is the `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: Even without these Enter/Exit, the script still hangs while msiexec doesn't do anything on the remote server.

Comment: what happens when you run that msiexec outside of the script by using Enter-PSSession?

Comment: It just sits like in the script. msiexec starts on the server, but does nothing.